# Invariant Violation: Tried to register two views with the same name WheelPicker

Tags: android, ios, react-native, expo

I am creating a react-native project using expo-managed workflow with the following dependencies in  package.json.
I use [wix/react-native-ui-lib](https://wix.github.io/react-native-ui-lib/) for creating my UI components in the react-native app.

```
{
  "dependencies": {
    "@codler/react-native-keyboard-aware-scroll-view": "^1.0.1",
    "@react-native-picker/picker": "1.9.11",
    "@react-navigation/bottom-tabs": "^5.11.11",
    "@react-navigation/native": "^5.9.4",
    "@react-navigation/stack": "^5.14.5",
    "expo": "~41.0.1",
    "expo-app-loading": "^1.0.3",
    "expo-linear-gradient": "~9.1.0",
    "expo-status-bar": "~1.0.4",
    "lodash": "^4.17.21",
    "react": "16.13.1",
    "react-dom": "16.13.1",
    "react-native": "https://github.com/expo/react-native/archive/sdk-41.0.0.tar.gz",
    "react-native-gesture-handler": "^1.10.3",
    "react-native-iphone-x-helper": "^1.3.1",
    "react-native-logs": "^3.0.3",
    "react-native-material-ripple": "^0.9.1",
    "react-native-phone-number-input": "^2.1.0",
    "react-native-reanimated": "~2.1.0",
    "react-native-responsive-fontsize": "^0.5.0",
    "react-native-responsive-screen": "^1.4.2",
    "react-native-root-toast": "^3.2.1",
    "react-native-screens": "~3.0.0",
    "react-native-snap-carousel": "^3.9.1",
    "react-native-svg": "12.1.0",
    "react-native-ui-lib": "^5.24.2",
    "react-native-web": "~0.13.12",
    "validator": "^13.6.0"
  },
  "devDependencies": {
    "@babel/core": "^7.9.0",
    "@babel/runtime": "^7.14.0",
    "@react-native-community/eslint-config": "^2.0.0",
    "@types/jest": "^26.0.23",
    "@types/lodash": "^4.14.169",
    "@types/react": "~16.9.35",
    "@types/react-native": "~0.63.2",
    "@types/react-native-material-ripple": "^0.9.1",
    "@types/react-native-snap-carousel": "^3.8.3",
    "@types/react-test-renderer": "^17.0.1",
    "babel-jest": "^26.6.3",
    "babel-plugin-module-resolver": "^3.2.0",
    "eslint": "^7.26.0",
    "eslint-import-resolver-babel-module": "^5.3.1",
    "eslint-plugin-import": "^2.23.2",
    "flush-promises": "^1.0.2",
    "jest": "^26.6.3",
    "metro-react-native-babel-preset": "^0.59.0",
    "prettier": "^2.3.0",
    "react-native-typescript-transformer": "^1.2.13",
    "react-test-renderer": "^17.0.2",
    "ts-jest": "^26.5.6",
    "typescript": "~4.0.0"
  },
}
```

When running the app, sometimes I get the following error message in the expo logs.

```
Invariant Violation: Tried to register two views with the same name WheelPicker
at node_modules/react-native/Libraries/Core/ExceptionsManager.js:104:6 in reportException
at node_modules/react-native/Libraries/Core/ExceptionsManager.js:171:19 in handleException
at node_modules/react-native/Libraries/Core/setUpErrorHandling.js:24:6 in handleError
at node_modules/expo-error-recovery/build/ErrorRecovery.fx.js:12:21 in ErrorUtils.setGlobalHandler$argument_0
at [native code]:null in flushedQueue
at [native code]:null in invokeCallbackAndReturnFlushedQueue
```

Is this due to a dependency error and how can this be removed ?